# How to set attributes in web.config only in release mode?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-config

I want set this attribute only in release mode:

```
<system.web>
    <httpCookies domain=".mySite.com" />
  </system.web>
```

This is my **Web.Release.Config**:

```
<system.web>
<httpCookies name="someName" domain=".mySite.com"  xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
</system.web>
```

and this is my **Web.Config**:

```
<system.web>
        <httpCookies name="someName"/>
      </system.web>
```

But the **httpCookies** property not have **name** attribute!!! and get error that this attribute not valid.

Comment: You could always try replacing the element. The syntax supports various other operations as well (e.g. insert). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should work - add this to your Web.Release.config file:

```
<system.web>
    <httpCookies domain=".mySite.com" xdt:Transform="Replace" />
</system.web>
```

You don't need the name attribute (it doesn't exist anyway)

This will be the result in the transformed web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <httpCookies domain=".mySite.com" />
</system.web>
```

Note that the `httpCookies` element must be present in your Web.config file for the transform to work.

Comment: that will replace the entire `httpCookies` node.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to change one attribute without replacing the entire node, do this in your `Web.Release.config`.

```
  <system.web>
...
    <httpCookies xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(domain)" domain=".mySite.com" />
```

That will leave the rest of the `httpCookies` attributes alone, and only change `domain`.  Make sure the new `domain=` appears after the `xdt:Transform` or it won't work.