# Delete an attribute in appSettings section with Web.config transformation

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, web.config-transform

Is it possible to transform the following Web.config appSettings file:

```
<example Hostname="https://xxx.build" ClientSecretKey="myclientsecret" clientId="555" clientSecret="666"></example>
```

into something like this:

```
<example Hostname="https://xxx.build" ClientSecretKey="myclientsecret">/example>
```

I want to remove clientId and clientSecret from that setting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the RemoveAttributes feature of web.config transformations for that. Your transform file would look like this:

```xml
<example xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(clientId,clientSecret)">
```

This will automatically remove those two attributes from the `example` element. An alternative approach is to replace the entire `example` element but leaving out the two attributes:

```xml
<example Hostname="https://xxx.build" ClientSecretKey="myclientsecret" xdt:Transform="Replace"></example>
```

Both transformations are tested and working with the [Web.config Transformation Tester](https://elmah.io/tools/webconfig-transformation-tester/). There is more information about XDT and examples in this blog post: [Web.config transformations - The definitive syntax guide](https://blog.elmah.io/web-config-transformations-the-definitive-syntax-guide/).

Comment: And to set them again: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18584901/how-to-set-attributes-in-web-config-only-in-release-mode#54914369

Comment: Not sure what you mean there. The task was to delete two attributes, right?

Comment: Just for reference for any others having issues. I had to delete them in some cases (like the question), but then work out how to add them back in other cases. :-)